# ASP.NET REST API Collections

Tags: c#, rest, api, collections

I'm trying to build REST API based on existing database model. I have already one built but I want to make it simpler and clear before I start coding client app. I've decided to use ASP.NET Core as back-end technology and WPF front end (also there will be Angular/Ionic frontend). The database model is very simple, it contains around 30 tables (different documents with related resources and collections).

So far API use flat URL - this way sometimes I have to post/put child object with its parent. Should I go with nested URL (API/Document/{id}/Item) to make sending object simpler or even use the only id which makes this object flat?

The second problem I have when I need data from child object for data needed to data grid source - should I add new method/controller to get ViewModel with all properties needed for data grid or should I get parent object collection first and then get child objects and construct view in client app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ultimately, this choice depends on many parameters and also on your team  preferences*. You didn't give enough details to give a absolute advice, but even though you did give them, there might not be any absolute answer anyway.

When in doubt, for both of your problems, I would recommend to **go for the flat, simple, complete data transfer objects**. (EDIT : of course won't be flat if you have linked collections, but still it would be simple and complete)

This has the advantage of **reducing the number of connections / calls to the API**, which have some overhead for all the network infrastructure, and for the client too.

Second, I think **this simplifies development** (but I admit this is debatable)

And also, about the second problem, it helps **separate the concerns between your API and your client app**. Building a ViewModel is often necessary (you maybe don't want to expose some informations, for security or performance reasons), but don't make it too complicated just for the client app; you want your API to be easily used by a new client / new version later.

---

To show you why it's usually worse to do many individual calls :

Imagine if you want to retrieve 40 documents.

If each document has Item1 and Item2, that would be 80 more calls if you have to retrieve Documents/1/Item1, Documents/1/Item2, etc.. !

Also, for your front-end development, you have to manage the callbacks (first call the document, once it's done get item1 and item2) which seems more complicated than getting the whole lot in one go (since ultimately you need to wait for everything to be there).

Worse, maybe some of the object has changed, and his children too, in between the call. You might end with Version A of your parent object, but with version B of it's children items !

---

Of course, there are some situations that could make the decomposed children items calls interesting.

If you often have to get only the item part of a document, without needing to reload the whole, that would be a good argument for that.

Or if the overall document is large, and you want to be able to display parts of the loaded documents before the complete loading is finished.

A last drawback I can see, when you have linked collection of related objects, is that you can have many repetition of linked objects. In this case it could make sense to do something more tricky if you need to avoid too many repetition, and have a few separate calls for main object, relations, and load related objects only once even if some are used multiple times can be beneficial.

Comment: Thank you for answer, You makes me sure I'm on the right track but as title of post says I aslo have problem with collections - should I make parent object flat and get related collection with second request or in this case add collection to parent object ?

Comment: I'll give the same kind of answer : prefer the "get everything in one call", unless you have a specific reason not do so. So, in this case of course the object would not be completely flat, but it would be the "simplest".

Comment: @user5671675 (I edited my anwer to make this point more clear)